# Count days when Returns1>Returns2 in R

Tags: r, database, return, dataset

I have a database formatted this way. I am asked to find the number of trading days (column "dates"), in 1990 where the Ret1 is than the Ret2?

```
Dates       Ret0     Ret1       Ret2    Num     SP      Ret3    Ret4      Ret5    
19260130   0.0561   2.3174    27412916  496  -0.1783   0.6457   12.74    2.2472    
19260227  -3.3046  -5.3510    27600952  500  -3.3296  -3.9979   12.18   -4.3956    
19260331  -6.4002  -9.6824    26683758  507  -5.7708  -6.7915   11.46   -5.9113    
19260430   3.7019   3.2946    24899756  512   3.8522   3.1441   11.72    2.2688    
19260528   1.2095   0.1035    25742578  515   1.3623   1.2011   11.81    0.7679    
19260630   5.3664   5.0487    26092831  520   5.6427   5.2142   12.32    4.3184    
19260731   3.1411   1.3076    27048916  509   4.0403   3.7547   12.88    4.5455    
19260831   2.8647   3.1002    27925440  516   2.9822   1.8924   13.10    1.7081    
19260930   0.5787  -0.6499    28889963  527   1.3420   1.4037   13.40    2.2901
```

I have tried to do something with this code but I can't seem to make it right. Any ideas?

`sum(format(df$Dates, "%Y" == "1990"[RED$Ret1>RED$Ret2]))`

Comment: Try this `sum(with(df, format(as.Date(Dates, "%Y%m%d"), "%Y") == "1990" & Ret1 > Ret2))`

Comment: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: this is the error that displays

Comment: Then just `sum(with(df, substr(Dates, 1L, 4L) == "1990" & Ret1 > Ret2))`